# Method yields invariable results when the result should be a positive integer

Tags: java, types

**Situation:**

Trying to test the following code but something strange is happening and I can't understand why:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int x = 30;
    if(product_n(x)>1000000)
        System.out.println("yes " + product_n(x));

    else
        System.out.println("nope "+ product_n(x));
}
// the following method returns the product of the n first integers(excluding 0)
public static int product_n(int n)
{
    int product = 1;
    if (n<=0)
        return 0;
    for(int i = n; i>(n-n);i--)
        product *=i;
    return product;
}
```

**results for the following numbers:**

```
30: 1409286144
31: 738197504
32,33: -2147483648
34: 0
```

So logically, as I increment x, the method should return an integer greater than the previous one. I'm guessing this has to do with the maximum amount of bytes the variable can hold. So what can explain the behaviour of 31,32,33,34. If i wanted to fix this, should i change the type from int to long?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try using double.**

An int variable takes up 4 bytes and can store a number in the range of:

```
-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647
```

This is not sufficient to store factorial of 30 which is

```
2.652528598E+32
```

A double variable takes up 8 bytes and can store a number in the range of:

```
±1.79769313486231570E+308
```

Code:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    double x = 30;
    if(product_n(x)>1000000)
        System.out.println("yes " + product_n(x));

    else
        System.out.println("nope "+ product_n(x));
}
// the following method returns the product of the n first integers(excluding 0)
public static double product_n(double n)
{
    double product = 1;
    if (n<=0)
        return 0;
    for(double i = n; i>(n-n);i--)
        product *=i;
    return product;
}
}
```

Output:

```
yes 2.652528598121911E32
```

You see the output as negative numbers in some cases because:

> The number of bits you need to store the results is less than the
>   number available. In such a case, overflow happens. When an overflow
>   happens, it just stores a part of the bits. Let's say you need 40 bits
>   to store the answer but you're only storing 32 of them. These 32 bits
>   were turning out to be negative numbers in some cases.

Comment: can you explain why it goes from a positive number, to a negative and then 0?

Comment: @RogerSteinberg It's called an integer overflow

Comment: When an overflow happens, it just stores a part of the bits. Let's say you need 40 bits to store the answer but you're only storing 32 of them. These 32 bits were turning out to be a large negative number. So, it prints No instead of Yes in the case of int.